# 301 Redirect methods

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

Need to implement over 30, 301 redirects. The templete that I was provided looks like it's something to be pasted in a `vhosts.conf` file or `httpd-conf`. There is no existing `vhosts.conf` file. So I included them in the `.htaccess` file. I wonder if that is best practice:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site.com
Redirect 301 / site.com/locations/location
</VirtualHost>
```

Below code used in the `.htaccess` file:

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

There was a different method in the .htaccess example. What are the differences with the one I used?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is used to redirect any www domain to non-www.
Your one practically does nothing. It takes `domain.com` domain and redirects it to itself.